# Access authenticated user in a Laravel 5.4 Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building an app that has pricing. I would want to assign some special price to some specific users.
In the model that has the price, I'm trying to use an accessor to "tweak" the price like so:

```php
public function getPriceAttribute($price)
{
    dd(auth()->user()); //this returns null

    if (auth()->check()) {
        $user = auth()->user();
       return $user->aDefinedRelationship()->first()->price;
    }

    return $price;
}
```

However `auth()->user()` always returns `null`.

I'm using the traditional Laravel authentication, no external library.

Please is there something I'm not doing right?

Any help would be appreciated.


More information:


auth.php

```php
return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],


'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Api\V1\Models\User::class,
    ],

],

];
```

ThePriceModel.php

```php
namespace App\Api\V1\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ThePriceModel extends Model
{
protected $table = 'prices';

protected $fillable = ['code', 'price'];

public function getPriceAttribute($price)
{
    dd(auth()->user()); //this returns null

    if (auth()->check()) {
        $user = auth()->user();
       return $user->aDefinedRelationship()->first()->price;
    }

    return $price;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you using the default guard? You need to prove more information as `auth()->user()` is valid and should work!

Comment: yes @Maverick, I'm using the default guard. `dd(auth()->user())` works as expected inside my controllers. I even tried accessing through the default (web) guard, `auth()->guard('web')->user()`, still returns `null`.

Comment: Does `auth()->check()` work?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, nope `auth()->check()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After every other thing failed, I resorted to using a global config variable.

in `config/constants.php`:

```
return [
  ...
  'user' => []
];
```

somewhere in my controller:

```
config()->set('constants.user', auth()->user());
```

Then in the model:

```
...
public function getPriceAttribute($price)
{
   $user = config()->get('constants.user');
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you were using API and this is why it didn't work. You could check for the user using this. You need to check API guard.

```
$user = \Auth::user() ?? \Auth::guard("api")->user();
```